# Why do we need to restart Appium every time we run group of tests?

Tags: java, appium

Why don't to set Appium running all the time? starting in the morning and stopping when day is complete, and running test scripts when we want.

Mac, Appium, Java.

Answer (score 0):

You could do that, just start it in the morning and stop it at night, but you could also do something better: Check to see in your test script if it is running, and if not, start it.  You could also then decide in your code whether or not to stop the service.

Below is the class I wrote for my own use with the help of many others by researching the net and putting it all together:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.ServerSocket;

import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import io.appium.java_client.service.local.AppiumDriverLocalService;
import io.appium.java_client.service.local.AppiumServiceBuilder;
import io.appium.java_client.service.local.flags.GeneralServerFlag;

/**
 * This class handles Appium Server
 * 
 * @author Bill Hileman
 */
public class AppiumServer {

    private AppiumDriverLocalService service;
    private AppiumServiceBuilder builder;
    private DesiredCapabilities cap;

    private int port = 4723;

    public void startServer() {
        // Set Capabilities
        cap = new DesiredCapabilities();
        cap.setCapability("noReset", "false");

        // Build the Appium service
        builder = new AppiumServiceBuilder();
        builder.withIPAddress("127.0.0.1");
        builder.usingPort(port);
        builder.withCapabilities(cap);
        builder.withArgument(GeneralServerFlag.SESSION_OVERRIDE);
        builder.withArgument(GeneralServerFlag.LOG_LEVEL, "error");

        // Start the server with the builder
        service = AppiumDriverLocalService.buildService(builder);
        service.start();
    }

    public void stopServer() {
        service.stop();
    }

    public boolean serverIsRunnning() {

        boolean isServerRunning = false;
        ServerSocket serverSocket;
        try {
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
            serverSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // If control comes here, then it means that the port is in use
            isServerRunning = true;
        } finally {
            serverSocket = null;
        }
        return isServerRunning;
    }

}
```

Comment: But I think there's something else to restart Appium.... I have been asked many times on job interview that question

Comment: There are multiple ways to start the Appium server/service, this is just one way, and it's using code.  Early on when I first started using Appium, I loaded the desktop server version - manually starting the program, and starting the server through that, and stopping/restarting using that as well, but like I said, I prefer the program to do it for me.  By the way, if this does help, please upvote the answer and/or select it as the accepted answer.  I'm glad to continue to answer questions.